# Meta refresh won't refresh

Tags: php, html, page-refresh

Is it required to have your meta refresh line to be above your `</head>` line? In my case, I can't because I would have to parse a few variables to dictation the # of seconds for the page to auto refresh. All this happens in the middle of my page and I also place this tag in the middle as well. My success rate has been pretty good, but sometimes it would not refresh at all.

Is there any other refreshing code that I can use that would guarantee a successful rate 100% of the time?

The tag I'm using here is:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?=$now['rsecs'];?>" url="&session<?=rand(1,999999999999)?>">
```

Comment: It seems that you've got wrong syntax [check this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Comment: I'm fairly sure this needs to be between the `<head></head>` tags. One question though, why do you need to change the refresh rate?

Comment: Yes, `<meta>` tags should be in the head. However, many browsers will not bork if you put them in the body - but they do need to be *correct* `<meta>` tags, which yours isn't: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/meta#attr-http-equiv

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $now['rsecs'];?>;URL='&session=<?php echo rand(1,999999999999);?>'">
```

I am not sure that just adding &session to the url path will send you to the right location. Perhaps include the full url?

```
URL='http://www.your-site.com/page.html?othervars=othervals&session=<?php echo rand(1,999999999999);?>
```

Comment: I really don't need the url - i added it because i was afraid some caching issues that may lead to not refreshing... aside from my url, do you see anything else that wouldn't allow this to be ran in the body section?

Answer (score 0):

See this url:-

http://davidwalsh.name/automatically-refresh-page-javascript-meta-tags

http://www.techtricky.com/how-to-refresh-page-or-part-of-the-page-automatically/

Try this

The JavaScript Method

```
var timer = null;
function auto_reload()
{
  window.location = 'http://domain.com/page.php';
}

 <body onload="timer = setTimeout('auto_reload()',10000);">
```

OR

The META Tag Method

The following refreshes the page every 30 seconds.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
</head>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;http://www.example.com" />
```

Or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com" />
```

Or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;URL=http://intranet/page.asp?x=123" />
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it, it worked fine as it worked with my previous. I just don't know why sometime it doesn't get refreshed. Is there any other method of reloading a page after X seconds?

Comment: i have added some new solution above answer take a look

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far. I don't know the seconds to reset until later down inside the body. I have queries to run etc then I will know the seconds the page has to reload.